# Chrome doesn't take new CSS and Javascript programming

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, updating

I'm having an issue with updating a web application in Chrome. It’s an ASPX site, but I don’t believe it’s relevant to this conversation. The issue is that our clients don’t get the latest programming in Chrome, because most of the time, it fails to release Javascript and CSS programming from memory, then proceeds to cause all kinds of mayhem while in use.

I tried placing this piece of code in the `<head>`, like many have suggested, but it doesn’t work all the time.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function reload_js(par_src) {
      src = $('script[src$="' + par_src + '"]').attr("src");
      $('script[src$="' + par_src + '"]').remove();
      $('<script/>').attr('src', par_src).appendTo('body');
    }

    reload_js("../../global/scripts/global_scripts.js");
    reload_js("scripts/main.js");
    reload_js("scripts/tabs/jquery.ui.core.js");
    reload_js("scripts/tabs/jquery.ui.widget.js");
    reload_js("scripts/tabs/jquery.ui.mouse.js");
    reload_js("scripts/tabs/jquery.ui.sortable.js");
    reload_js("scripts/tabs/jquery.ui.tabs.js");
    reload_js("scripts/chat_room.js");

  </script>
```

And I use this Javascript file to refresh my css's. One that I found here.

```
<script src="../../global/scripts/css_refresh.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm scared that these methods cause unnecessary overhead, because they run every time a page is loaded.

Could one of you experts please tell me if this is the most efficient method for updating? Or perhaps recommend a better method to keep these files up to date?

Comment: That won't work at all.  Learn about HTTP caching headers.

Comment: Use timestamp for each request and/or change http-caching header.
[ HTTP Caching ](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to fix this is to add an identifier to the script/style-files. Just add something like ?version=12 (and update the number for each release) then the browser will fetch the newest file. You can also use some sort of server-side date-option after the ?of course, to force a new fetch every day or similar.

Comment: I tried that, but it fails as well. It doesn't take the new programming.